# Angular - Share Data Between Sibling Components Without Sharing Between Instances

Tags: angular, service, components, instantiation

I'm writing a module that contains three separate components. These components work together, so it makes sense to use a Service to help keep track of everything.

```
|    
|- wrapper.component.ts
|
|- wrapper.service.ts
|
|- wrapper.module.ts
|
|- child-component1.component.ts
|
|- child-component2.component.ts
```

The problem is that, if you create two instances of the base component in the app, the Service shares the data between both instances of the component.

What's the proper way to share data between siblings without sharing it between all instances of the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing the service at the component level:

```
@Component({
    ....
    providers: [myService]
})
```

This way the service instance is shared between the component and its children, but not other instances of the component.

Comment: Thanks, Vega! That's what I was looking for but couldn't find on Google. I'll give it a try! Do I need to include the service in each Component, then?

Comment: Yes, each one. And don't provide at module level.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can emit an event using event emitter from child 1 component to parent
2. change the input to child 2 from parent with data emitted from child 1
3. Access the data in ngOnChange of child 2

Comment: Angular component seems to be sharing state with all instances. I made a demo that shows the issue. My file upload updates the topmost instance instead of the instance that I click. Thx  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-instance-output?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html